# Only first iteration of loop outputs dynamic variables

Tags: php, loops, foreach

With this code:

```
$images = array(
    '0.jpg',
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg'
);

$img_w_0 = 312;
$img_h_0 = 246;
$img_w_1 = 485;
$img_h_1 = 442;
$img_w_2 = 380;
$img_h_2 = 289;

foreach ($images as $i=>$image):
    echo ' Width = '. ${'img_w_'.$image[$i]};
    echo ' Height = '. ${'img_h_'.$image[$i]};
endforeach;
```

only the first iteration of my loop is outputting values. This is what I get:

```
Width = 312 Height = 246 Width =  Height =  Width =  Height =
```

What I want to get is

```
Width = 312 Height = 246 Width = 485 Height = 442 Width = 380 Height = 289
```

I've created a [Codepad](http://codepad.org/zTQzBCSP) to illustrate better.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you think the `$i` in `$image[$i]` is…?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach ($images as $i=>$image):
//    var_dump(substr($image, 0, 1));
    echo ' Width = '. ${'img_w_'.substr($image, 0, 1)};
    echo ' Height = '. ${'img_h_'.substr($image, 0, 1)};
endforeach;
```

You want to append `0, 1 and 2` but you was appending `0, ., j, p, g`.

---

According with comments:

```
substr($image, 0, 1)
```

is equal

```
$i
```

but your code was iterating over letters in names of images.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$i`?

Comment: `$image[0]` would’ve done just fine too…